# about contextmenustrip

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

I've added contextmenustrip control at the time of designing of my application. And i want to edit that contxt menu at run time. And i want to add another menu & submenu on that context menu. And i want to add handler function for that runtime created menus. 
Whether is it possible? If possible then provide some documentation.

thanks.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for wasting my time. Now that you have worked out what component you are talking about, why don't you at least spell it correctly with the correct letter case. C# is case-sensitive! It you want an example look in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx).

Comment: @David Heffernan: I'm so sorry for wasting your important time. I know it's my  fault. Sorry for that.

Comment: That's OK. I've cooled off now. I just had a nice answer with links and code for ContextMenu, and then you obviously realised that wasn't what you were after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer of my issue. 
the sample code used for solving this issue is as follows-

```
ToolStripMenuItem addContactToGroup = new ToolStripMenuItem();
addContactToGroup.Name = "addContactToGroupToolStripMenuItem";
addContactToGroup.Text = "Add Contact To Group";
addContactToGroup.Click += new System.EventHandler(addContactToGroup_Click);
this.contextMenuStripXtraGrid.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { addContactToGroup });
gridControl1.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStripXtraGrid;
```

here `this` means form where contextmenustrip control is inserted.